# Part of body not staying with armature when bone moved

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

Whenever I move the beak bone for the mesh I am making it always moves way too much and moves the wrong part of the body. Here is a clip of an animation that I am not done working on:
[image]

The gif isn't a perfect representation but you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had two bones affecting the same part of the mesh and I was moving both bones.